# How do i find the equivalence class of R and (1,2)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let R be the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers such that ((a,b), (c,d)) ∈ R if and only if ad = ab.

Show that R is an equivalence relation
What is the equivalence class of (1,2)?

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence class of R is rational number and (1,2) is $\frac{1}{2}$.